# Efficient C++ software stack for web development

Tags: c++, web-services

What C++ software stack do developers use to create custom fast, responsive and not very resource hungry web services?

Comment: Have you had a look at FastCGI running on Lighttpd?

Comment: more details?  What kind of a web service you are talking about?

Comment: In that case look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298113/how-can-i-implement-a-restful-webservice-using-c

Comment: You could also try [CppCMS](http://cppcms.com/wikipp/en/page/main).

Comment: I've tried CppCMS. I found it somewhat bloated and poorly documented. I also wanted to look for more customizable solutions that would allow me to work with my preferred technologies (Google templates, SOCI, etc...) more easily. Didn't really like their dual (GPL, commercial) version release scheme and open source policy.

Comment: @JuozasDomarkas Several notes: it is not licensed under GPL but LGPL witch is much more permissive. Also it is not correct to say that it is not customizable to work with "SOCI" or "Google templates".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend you to take a look on CppCMS:

http://cppcms.com

It [exactly](http://cppcms.com/wikipp/en/page/when_to_use_cppcms) fits the situation you had described:

- performance-oriented (preferably web service) software stack
- for C++ web development.
- It should have a low memory footprint
- work on UNIX (FreeBSD) and Linux systems
- perform well under high server load and be able to handle many requests with great efficiency
- [as I plan to use it in a virtual environment] where resources will be to some extent limited.

> So far I have only come across Staff WSF, Boost, Poco libraries. The latter two could be used to implement a custom web server...

The problem that web server is about 2% of web development there are so much stuff to handle:

- web templates
- sessions
- cache
- forms
- security-security-security - which is far from being trivial

And much more, that is why you need web frameworks.

Answer (score 3):

You could write an [apache module](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/linux/apache/ch15_01.htm), and put all your processing code in there.

Or there's [CppCMS](http://cppcms.com/wikipp/en/page/main), or [Treefrog](http://www.treefrogframework.org/) or for writing web services (not web sites) use [gSOAP](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html) or [Apache Axis](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/c/core/)

But ultimately, there's no "easy to use framework" because C++ developers like to build apps from smaller components. There's no Ruby-style framework, but there is all manner of libraries for handling xml or whatever, and Apache offers the http protocol bits in the module spec so you can build up your app quite happily using whatever pieces make sense to you. Now whether there's a market for bundling this up to make something easier to use is another matter.

Personally, the best web app system I wrote (for a company) used a very think web layer in the web server (IIS and ASP, but this applies to any webserver, use php for example) that did nothing except act as a gateway to pass the data from the requests through to a C++ service. The C++ service could then be written completely as a normal C++ command line server with well-defined entry points, using as thin an RPC system as possible (shared memory, but you may want to check out ZeroMQ), which not only increased security but  allowed us to easily scale by shifting the services to app servers and running the web servers on different hardware. It was also really easy to test.